# radio button getting automatically unchecked after some time

Tags: vb6

i have build a quiz app in VB . Radio  buttons for answers are being selected and accordingly score is being calculated and displayed correctly. But the radio buttons are getting automatically unchecked after sometime and score is reset to 0. i am not being able to figure out why is this happening. can anyone help?

Comment: Some more information would be good. Can we see some of the code involved in calculating score?

Can you explain how the radio buttons are structured (Control indexes etc)

Comment: I want to get a burger but I'm not sure if I have enough money in my pocket! could you please tell me if I can buy it or not?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the form is being unloaded, then displayed again. You can see if this is the case by putting a breakpoint int the form load handler.